# CSS#/HTML5 Nested tables and child padding in Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm currently attempting to set up a multipanel widget for my UI library, SlateJS. Basically, a multipanel widget fills all space made available to it with a number of horizontally or vertically aligned panels. Each panel can have a toolbar associated with it.

I'm using a series of CSS tables to divide the available space, which is working well. The problem is when the layout is horizontal for some reason the inner tables refuse to play nice with any element that has padding. I can't find the source of the padding issues. I've been diagnosing in Chrome for about 17 hours now, and I still can't find the source of this padding.

What happens is if I add an element to the content pane of a panel that's nested inside of a multipanel, the outer table-cell acts as though it has a margin-top value that's equal to the padding value of the content item. It's really strange, because the inner table cells shouldn't be affecting the flow of the outer cells.

Here's a link to a live demo of the problem in action:

http://virogenesys.ddns.net/mapeditor/

Note: The site only works in Chrome at the moment. Also note that this site uses shadow dom pretty heavily, so you'll have to dig through the guts of the shadow dom in order to see the structure.

Here's a basic representation of what I'm doing:

**SlateJS.css**:

```
slate-app {
    display: block;
}

/* LIGHTBOX */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

slate-app::shadow > .appContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

slate-app::shadow > .appContainer > slate-lightbox {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

slate-app::shadow > .appContainer > slate-lightbox[visible="true"] {
    display: block;
}

/* MULTIPANEL */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

slate-multipanel {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

slate-multipanel > * {
    display: none;
}

slate-multipanel::shadow > .panelTable {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

slate-multipanel::shadow .panelRow0, slate-multipanel::shadow .panelRow1 {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

slate-multipanel::shadow .panelRow1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    cursor: ns-resize;
}

slate-multipanel::shadow .panelCell0, slate-multipanel::shadow .panelCell1 {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

slate-multipanel::shadow .panelCell1 {
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: ew-resize;
}

slate-multipanel::shadow slate-expander {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: crosshair;
    display: block;
}

/* PANEL */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

slate-panel {
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

slate-panel > slate-pane:first-of-type {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}

slate-panel > slate-toolbar:first-of-type {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}

/* PANE */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

slate-pane::shadow > .paneCell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

/* TOOLBAR */
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

slate-toolbar::shadow > .toolbarCell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

**Markup generated by Slate.js and her relevant extensions**:

```
<slate-app class="mapEditor">
    <slate-multipanel orientation="horizontal">
        #shadow-root
            <div class="panelTable">
                <div class="panelRow0">
                    <div class="panelCell0">
                        <content select=".panel1"></content>
                        <slate-expander orientation="left" draggable="true"></slate-expander>
                        <slate-expander orientation="right" draggable="true"></slate-expander>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panelCell1"></div>
                    <div class="panelCell0">
                        <content select=".panel2"></content>
                        <slate-expander orientation="left" draggable="true"></slate-expander>
                        <slate-expander orientation="right" draggable="true"></slate-expander>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panelCell1"></div>
                    <div class="panelCell0">
                        <content select=".panel3"></content>
                        <slate-expander orientation="left" draggable="true"></slate-expander>
                        <slate-expander orientation="right" draggable="true"></slate-expander>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <slate-panel class="panel1">
            <slate-pane>
                #shadow-root
                    <div class="paneCell">
                        <content></content>
                    </div>
                <span>HERP</span>
            </slate-pane>
            <slate-toolbar>
                #shadow-root
                    <div class="toolbarCell">
                        <content></content>
                    </div>
                <span>DERP</span>
            </slate-toolbar>
        </slate-panel>
        <slate-panel class="panel2">
            <slate-pane>
                #shadow-root
                    <div class="paneCell">
                        <content></content>
                    </div>
                <button style="padding:32px;" onclick="var pnode = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;if(pnode.getAttribute('orientation')==='horizontal'){pnode.setAttribute('orientation','vertical');}else{pnode.setAttribute('orientation','horizontal');}">TEST</button>
            </slate-pane>
            <slate-toolbar>
                #shadow-root
                    <div class="toolbarCell">
                        <content></content>
                    </div>
                <span>DERP</span>
            </slate-toolbar>
        </slate-panel>
        <slate-panel class="panel3">
            <slate-pane>
                #shadow-root
                    <div class="paneCell">
                        <content></content>
                    </div>
                <span>HERP</span>
            </slate-pane>
            <slate-toolbar>
                #shadow-root
                    <div class="toolbarCell">
                        <content></content>
                    </div>
                <span>DERP</span>
            </slate-toolbar>
        </slate-panel>
    </slate-multipanel>
</slate-app>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyZki.png

As you can see from the image above, the neighboring table cells are offset for some reason by the same amount as the padding in the child element of their neighbor. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening, and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was caused by vertical-align being baseline on the outer table DIVs. Hilariously enough, a simple modification of:

```
slate-multipanel::shadow .panelCell0, slate-multipanel::shadow .panelCell1 {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Did the trick. The outer and inner divs now behave in both horizontal and vertical orientation.